# What is the best way to approach this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, python, machine-learning-model

I'm new with data science, but I'm familiar with python3.

I'd like to solve a problem with machine learning, but I'm totally new to this field, which is why I am looking for someone kind enough to discuss possible solutions with me.
Edit: I realised that this isn't a 'machine learning' problem.

Anyone bored enough to help me think about his problem? :)

Background: You are the manager of a new upcoming soccer club. You can spend 40,5 on players and you have to buy a total of 12! You need **1 goalkeeper** (choosen from df1 (n=10), **4 defensive players** (choosen from df2 (n=45)), **4 mid-fielders** (choosen from df3 (n=55)) and **3 strikers** (choosen from df4 (n=27). Each player has a price and a value, called 'points' in the following.

Task: Choose a total of **12 players** with a **budget of 40,5** as described above. The goal is to find the team that holds the most 'points', when the points of all 12 players are summed together.

See the code that generates the four dataframes here:

```
###Import pandas library  
import pandas as pd  

###Rawdata (pre processed) as nested list
players = [['Baumann', 'Hoffenheim', 3.2, 158, 'Tor', 49.375], ['Bürki', 'Dortmund', 4.2, 203, 'Tor', 48.33333333333333], ['Casteels', 'Wolfsburg', 3.6, 151, 'Tor', 41.94444444444444], ['Jarstein', 'Hertha', 3.5, 182, 'Tor', 52.0], ['Müller', 'Mainz', 2.6, 109, 'Tor', 41.92307692307692], ['Neuer', 'Bayern', 4.3, 102, 'Tor', 23.72093023255814], ['Nübel', 'Schalke', 2.8, 83, 'Tor', 29.642857142857146], ['Pavlenka', 'Bremen', 3.6, 178, 'Tor', 49.44444444444444], ['Schwolow', 'Freiburg', 3.8, 193, 'Tor', 50.78947368421053], ['Sommer', 'Gladbach', 4.3, 216, 'Tor', 50.23255813953489], ['Trapp', 'Frankfurt', 3.6, 175, 'Tor', 48.61111111111111], ['Akanji', 'Dortmund', 3.0, 72, 'Abw', 24.0], ['Alaba', 'Bayern', 4.0, 137, 'Abw', 34.25], ['Ayhan', 'Düsseldorf', 2.6, 92, 'Abw', 35.38461538461539], ['Bender', 'Leverkusen', 2.6, 70, 'Abw', 26.923076923076923], ['Bender', 'Leverkusen', 3.0, 85, 'Abw', 28.333333333333332], ['Boateng', 'Bayern', 3.0, 53, 'Abw', 17.666666666666668], ['Brooks', 'Wolfsburg', 2.5, 79, 'Abw', 31.6], ['Brosinski', 'Mainz', 1.7, 40, 'Abw', 23.529411764705884], ['Dragovic', 'Leverkusen', 2.0, 50, 'Abw', 25.0], ['Elvedi', 'Gladbach', 2.7, 80, 'Abw', 29.629629629629626], ['Gießelmann', 'Düsseldorf', 1.8, 51, 'Abw', 28.333333333333332], ['Ginter', 'Gladbach', 3.2, 90, 'Abw', 28.125], ['Günter', 'Freiburg', 2.6, 93, 'Abw', 35.76923076923077], ['Halstenberg', 'Leipzig', 3.2, 114, 'Abw', 35.625], ['Hasebe', 'Frankfurt', 3.4, 111, 'Abw', 32.64705882352941], ['Heintz', 'Freiburg', 2.2, 76, 'Abw', 34.54545454545454], ['Hinteregger', 'Frankfurt', 2.8, 78, 'Abw', 27.857142857142858], ['Hoffmann', 'Düsseldorf', 1.5, 32, 'Abw', 21.333333333333332], ['Hübner', 'Hoffenheim', 2.7, 31, 'Abw', 11.481481481481481], ['Hummels', 'Dortmund', 4.0, 83, 'Abw', 20.75], ['Kimmich', 'Bayern', 4.3, 156, 'Abw', 36.27906976744186], ['Klostermann', 'Leipzig', 3.4, 127, 'Abw', 37.35294117647059], ['Knoche', 'Wolfsburg', 2.6, 87, 'Abw', 33.46153846153846], ['Konaté', 'Leipzig', 3.4, 112, 'Abw', 32.94117647058824], ['Laimer', 'Leipzig', 2.2, 49, 'Abw', 22.27272727272727], ['Lienhart', 'Freiburg', 1.6, 23, 'Abw', 14.375], ['Max', 'Augsburg', 2.5, 69, 'Abw', 27.6], ['Moisander', 'Bremen', 2.8, 70, 'Abw', 25.0], ['Nastasic', 'Schalke', 2.2, 25, 'Abw', 11.363636363636363], ['Niakhaté', 'Mainz', 2.0, 40, 'Abw', 20.0], ['Orban', 'Leipzig', 3.6, 122, 'Abw', 33.888888888888886], ['Pavard', 'Bayern', 3.0, 26, 'Abw', 8.666666666666666], ['Piszczek', 'Dortmund', 2.6, 73, 'Abw', 28.076923076923077], ['Posch', 'Hoffenheim', 1.7, 37, 'Abw', 21.764705882352942], ['Rekik', 'Hertha', 2.0, 34, 'Abw', 17.0], ['Roussillon', 'Wolfsburg', 3.5, 148, 'Abw', 42.285714285714285], ['Schulz', 'Dortmund', 3.8, 144, 'Abw', 37.89473684210527], ['Stark', 'Hertha', 2.5, 61, 'Abw', 24.4], ['Süle', 'Bayern', 4.0, 106, 'Abw', 26.5], ['Tah', 'Leverkusen', 3.8, 133, 'Abw', 35.0], ['Upamecano', 'Leipzig', 2.2, 43, 'Abw', 19.545454545454543], ['Vogt', 'Hoffenheim', 3.0, 86, 'Abw', 28.666666666666668], ['Wendell', 'Leverkusen', 2.0, 21, 'Abw', 10.5], ['Wendt', 'Gladbach', 2.0, 51, 'Abw', 25.5], ['William', 'Wolfsburg', 1.7, 47, 'Abw', 27.647058823529413], ['Zimmermann', 'Düsseldorf', 1.8, 52, 'Mit', 28.88888888888889], ['Amiri', 'Leverkusen', 3.2, 45, 'Mit', 14.0625], ['Arnold', 'Wolfsburg', 3.0, 105, 'Mit', 35.0], ['Baier', 'Augsburg', 1.8, 45, 'Mit', 25.0], ['Baku', 'Mainz', 1.5, 35, 'Mit', 23.333333333333332], ['Brekalo', 'Wolfsburg', 2.2, 37, 'Mit', 16.818181818181817], ['Caligiuri', 'Schalke', 3.0, 63, 'Mit', 21.0], ['Coman', 'Bayern', 7.0, 121, 'Mit', 17.285714285714285], ['Demirbay', 'Leverkusen', 5.0, 147, 'Mit', 29.4], ['Demme', 'Leipzig', 2.8, 81, 'Mit', 28.92857142857143], ['Duda', 'Hertha', 3.2, 114, 'Mit', 35.625], ['Eggestein', 'Bremen', 4.8, 155, 'Mit', 32.29166666666667], ['Fernandes', 'Frankfurt', 1.5, 35, 'Mit', 23.333333333333332], ['Frantz', 'Freiburg', 2.0, 62, 'Mit', 31.0], ['Gacinovic', 'Frankfurt', 1.6, 27, 'Mit', 16.875], ['Gnabry', 'Bayern', 6.5, 148, 'Mit', 22.76923076923077], ['Goretzka', 'Bayern', 5.0, 118, 'Mit', 23.6], ['Gregoritsch', 'Augsburg', 2.6, 57, 'Mit', 21.923076923076923], ['Grifo', 'Hoffenheim', 3.0, 98, 'Mit', 32.666666666666664], ['Grillitsch', 'Hoffenheim', 3.6, 108, 'Mit', 30.0], ['Grujic', 'Hertha', 3.0, 80, 'Mit', 26.666666666666668], ['Guilavogui', 'Wolfsburg', 3.0, 76, 'Mit', 25.333333333333332], ['Haberer', 'Freiburg', 2.5, 74, 'Mit', 29.6], ['Hahn', 'Augsburg', 2.0, 41, 'Mit', 20.5], ['Havertz', 'Leverkusen', 8.0, 247, 'Mit', 30.875], ['Hazard', 'Dortmund', 6.0, 147, 'Mit', 24.5], ['Kalou', 'Hertha', 2.6, 71, 'Mit', 27.307692307692307], ['Kampl', 'Leipzig', 3.6, 117, 'Mit', 32.5], ['Khedira', 'Augsburg', 2.8, 84, 'Mit', 30.000000000000004], ['Klaassen', 'Bremen', 3.5, 106, 'Mit', 30.285714285714285], ['Klaus', 'Wolfsburg', 1.8, 20, 'Mit', 11.11111111111111], ['Kohr', 'Frankfurt', 2.0, 34, 'Mit', 17.0], ['Kostic', 'Frankfurt', 3.6, 137, 'Mit', 38.05555555555556], ['Kramer', 'Gladbach', 2.4, 48, 'Mit', 20.0], ['Latza', 'Mainz', 1.8, 41, 'Mit', 22.77777777777778], ['Leckie', 'Hertha', 1.5, 33, 'Mit', 22.0], ['Morales', 'Düsseldorf', 1.3, 23, 'Mit', 17.692307692307693], ['Müller', 'Bayern', 6.5, 149, 'Mit', 22.923076923076923], ['Neuhaus', 'Gladbach', 3.2, 95, 'Mit', 29.6875], ['Reus', 'Dortmund', 8.0, 206, 'Mit', 25.75], ['Rode', 'Frankfurt', 2.3, 47, 'Mit', 20.434782608695652], ['Sabitzer', 'Leipzig', 4.0, 106, 'Mit', 26.5], ['Sahin', 'Bremen', 1.8, 24, 'Mit', 13.333333333333332], ['Sallai', 'Freiburg', 1.6, 24, 'Mit', 15.0], ['Sancho', 'Dortmund', 7.0, 207, 'Mit', 29.571428571428573], ['Schmid', 'Freiburg', 1.8, 50, 'Mit', 27.77777777777778], ['Skrzybski', 'Schalke', 1.8, 25, 'Mit', 13.88888888888889], ['Sobottka', 'Düsseldorf', 1.6, 25, 'Mit', 15.625], ['Steffen', 'Wolfsburg', 2.2, 65, 'Mit', 29.545454545454543], ['Strobl', 'Gladbach', 2.0, 61, 'Mit', 30.5], ['Thiago', 'Bayern', 6.5, 143, 'Mit', 22.0], ['Weigl', 'Dortmund', 2.6, 40, 'Mit', 15.384615384615383], ['Witsel', 'Dortmund', 5.0, 135, 'Mit', 27.0], ['Zakaria', 'Gladbach', 2.8, 83, 'Mit', 29.642857142857146], ['Zuber', 'Hoffenheim', 2.2, 48, 'Mit', 21.818181818181817], ['Bailey', 'Leverkusen', 3.4, 64, 'Stu', 18.823529411764707], ['Bebou', 'Hoffenheim', 3.0, 66, 'Stu', 22.0], ['Bellarabi', 'Leverkusen', 4.2, 94, 'Stu', 22.38095238095238], ['Burgstaller', 'Schalke', 2.4, 28, 'Stu', 11.666666666666668], ['Eggestein', 'Bremen', 1.8, 41, 'Stu', 22.77777777777778], ['Füllkrug', 'Bremen', 3.0, 21, 'Stu', 7.0], ['Götze', 'Dortmund', 4.8, 124, 'Stu', 25.833333333333336], ['Hennings', 'Düsseldorf', 2.0, 63, 'Stu', 31.5], ['Herrmann', 'Gladbach', 2.0, 35, 'Stu', 17.5], ['Ibisevic', 'Hertha', 2.8, 83, 'Stu', 29.642857142857146], ['Lewandowski', 'Bayern', 8.5, 218, 'Stu', 25.647058823529413], ['Lukebakio', 'Hertha', 3.2, 78, 'Stu', 24.375], ['Onisiwo', 'Mainz', 2.5, 90, 'Stu', 36.0], ['Osako', 'Bremen', 2.2, 51, 'Stu', 23.18181818181818], ['Paciencia', 'Frankfurt', 2.4, 36, 'Stu', 15.0], ['Petersen', 'Freiburg', 3.0, 93, 'Stu', 31.0], ['Poulsen', 'Leipzig', 5.8, 157, 'Stu', 27.06896551724138], ['Quaison', 'Mainz', 2.0, 54, 'Stu', 27.0], ['Raman', 'Schalke', 2.8, 113, 'Stu', 40.35714285714286], ['Rashica', 'Bremen', 3.7, 113, 'Stu', 30.54054054054054], ['Rebic', 'Frankfurt', 3.5, 109, 'Stu', 31.142857142857142], ['Richter', 'Augsburg', 2.6, 38, 'Stu', 14.615384615384615], ['Selke', 'Hertha', 2.4, 55, 'Stu', 22.916666666666668], ['Volland', 'Leverkusen', 6.5, 172, 'Stu', 26.46153846153846], ['Waldschmidt', 'Freiburg', 3.2, 95, 'Stu', 29.6875], ['Weghorst', 'Wolfsburg', 6.0, 176, 'Stu', 29.333333333333332], ['Werner', 'Leipzig', 7.0, 171, 'Stu', 24.428571428571427]]

###Create the pandas DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(players, columns = ['name', 'team','price','points','position','points per price'])  


###seperate into the four dataframes by position (e.g. goalkeeper, striker,..)
df1 = df.loc[df['position'] == "Tor"] 


df2 = df.loc[df['position'] == "Abw"] 


df3 = df.loc[df['position'] == "Mit"] 


df4 = df.loc[df['position'] == "Stu"]
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps the question would be easier to understand and work with if you provide the python code to make the dataframe so that your question can be easily reproduced?

Comment: This is a very standard use of dynamic programming.

Comment: Hi! What is it that you like to do? Do you wan't an algorithm that optimises for points given constraints, do you want to teach an algorithm to follow your examples and extrapolate that to a policy or do you want to define a function that expresses the utility of a choice?

Comment: I'll update the question with the dataframes posted at the end of the question in form of a nested list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest you to use more traditional approaches of coding such as dynamic programming or Greedy method to solve this rather than going for machine learning because in your question as far as i can understand there is nothing much that a machine learning algorithm can do for you in such a problem because there is simply nothing to learn here , so go for optimization techniques such as DP this actually to me looks like a problem similar to knapsack problem here your prices of items can act as weights and 40 as your maximum capacity then you can proceed i guess similarly in the  way knapsack problem is solved using DP(i prefer it).Lastly, since you are new to machine learning i should tell you by reading your problem there is not much machine learning you can do here

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I appreciate it. I think you are right and i'm going to read on the knapsack problem. I thought that i needed some kind of 'intelligent' approach, because of the high number of possible combinations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the standard backtracking approach, but it will require 5 billion operations.